# What are some applications of computing the permanent of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What are some applications that require computing the [permanent of a matrix?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent)

One application I know of is related to graph theory and matchings. Apparently, the number of perfect matchings of a bipartite graph is the permanent of its incidence matrix.

I am curious to know more applications of matrix permanent.

Comment: There is the question of permanent VS determinant. I think that one can easily compute the determinant using the permanent on a bigger matrix, but the main question is how to compute the permanent using the determinant.

Answer (score 5):

Valiant proved that [the permanent is $\# P$-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_is_sharp-P-complete), which means that an efficient algorithm for computing the permanent can be used to solve any problem in [$\# P$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P), such as counting the number of satisfying assignment to a CNF, the number of Hamiltonian circuits, the number of $k$-colorings and so on. In particular, it could be used to solve NP-complete problems.

Comment: While that's true, I don't think it's an application of computing the permanent _per se_. I don't think you'd say, for example, that an application of the travelling salesman problem is determining whether a 3-CNF formula is satisfiable.

Comment: No, but SAT solvers are used universally exactly because SAT is NP-complete. The importance of the permanent in TCS lies in its $\# P$ universality.